# Is it possible to make a GraphQL request with the M language?

Tags: powerbi, m

I'm trying to build the architecture for a Power BI custom data connector, that will consume a GraphQL API. I'm currently thinking about 2 approaches;

1. Creating a wrapper REST layer, to avoid having to deal with GraphQl in the custom data connector
2. Consuming the GraphQl API directly in the custom data connector.

Is option 2 possible at all, i.e. can you make GraphQl requests with the M language?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/petrsvihlik/cc34a6cf1882d515139c5b27f37cf99e